# Troubleshoot partitioning of Windows 10 disk space

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I need to shrink my C drive partition to make room for Linux dual boot.

There is ~150gb free space on disk(it displays as such), but Windows returns an error tha t there is not enough space when I try to shrink.

There are 3 partitions right now: EFI System, then C:, then 1.46 unallocated, then 1000mb recovery partition.

I suspect the trouble is a result of the C drive being sandwiched between two other partitions.

How can I fix this problem and partition my drive?

Comment: You will have to shrink the C partition in order to create a large enough partition for Linux.

Comment: As a side note, if you're looking to use Ubuntu you can use Wubi to do the hard work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**>I suspect the trouble is a result of the C drive being sandwiched between two other partitions.**
If your partition order is “EFI System -> C -> 1.46 unallocated -> 1000mb recovery partition”, then, shrinking volume on C will reduce volume space on C, and increase the space on unallocated partition.

Suggestions for your reference:
1.  Disk Manager – Action – Rescan Disks.
2.  Using Disk Cleanup to clear caching files.
3.  Running Disk Defragment.
4.  Turned off System Restore and Hibernation.